# Почему при вызове свойства get - код выдает undefined?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

Пример из книги, который я не могу понять. Пометку в коде я сделал. Почему при вызове свойства get - код выдает undefined. хотя в моем понимании Grid( 5 , 5) есть, vector(1 , 1) есть.

```js
function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Vector.prototype.plus = function(other) {
  return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
}

var grid = ["top left", "top middle", "top right",
  "bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"
];

function Grid(width, height) {
  this.space = new Array(width * height);
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

Grid.prototype.isInside = function(vector) {
  return vector.x >= 0 && vector.x < this.width &&
    vector.y >= 0 && vector.y < this.height;
}

Grid.prototype.get = function(vector) {
  return this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y];
}

Grid.prototype.set = function(vector, value) {
  this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y] = value;
}

var grid = new Grid(5, 5);
console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1))); //< --вот тут вопрос.
// → undefined
grid.set(new Vector(1, 1), "X");
console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));
// → X
```

Comment: Если Вы туда ничего не клали, что Вы там рссчитываете найти?

Comment: `new Array(n)` инициализирует *пустой* массив размерностью `n`. Логично, что обращение к любой ячейке пустого массива возвращает `undefined`. Во втором случае вы вы записали в ячейку `"X"` и потом ее же и получили.

Comment: Вы правы. в функции grid создаётся пустой массив. Спасибо.